# Embedding a plot in a website with Python/bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to statically embed a bokeh plot in a personal website, and am encountering some behavior I do not understand.  Basically, I am generating a plot using bokeh as follows:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bplt
import numpy as np

x=np.random.random(100)
y=np.random.random(100)

bplt.output_file("t.html")
plot=bplt.line(x,y)

##the following line refers to the bokeh installed on my home computer
print plot.create_html_snippet(
           static_path='/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/static/')

##the following line refers to the bokeh installed on my remote computer
#print plot.create_html_snippet(
#           static_path='/opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/static/')
```

So far so good.  This produces a file that looks like `(random garbage).embed.js`, and a prints string containing html syntax that I manually copy into an html file I am calling `testembed.html`, which I have reproduced below:

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>Simple Embed Example</h2>
<p>This is where my plot should be:</p>
<p>
<!--The next 4 lines are the output of the print statement from the python code-->
<script src="ccbd451a-6995-4dd2-b99c-e4140b362997.embed.js"
        bokeh_plottype="embeddata"
        bokeh_modelid="ccbd451a-6995-4dd2-b99c-e4140b362997"
        bokeh_modeltype="Plot" async="true"></script>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

If I have the python code reference my *local* python installation and copy the generated files (.html and .embed.js) to my local computer, I **can see** the plot in the html file.

However, what I really want to do is have this run on a remote computer, and have the html file accessible through the web on my personal site.

When I have `static_path` refer to my *remote computer's* python install (as shown above, commented out), I **can't see the plot** in the html page when I access it through the web (ie, going to http://mywebsite.com/testembed.html).  I have no idea why this is happening.

For reference, here is the code where the html snippet function is defined:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/objects.py#L309
and I note there is an option I am *not* passing in `create_html_snippet`, ie,  `embed_base_url`, which *could* have something to do with this.

Thanks in advance!
Mike

**EDIT**
I took `bigreddot`'s advice, which solved the problem.  The actual problem I had been having was that the webserver I was using was, for security purposes, only able to access things in my `public_html` directory.  The workaround was to `rsync` the `bokeh/static` directory into my `public_html` and point to that:

```
rsync -ax /opt/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bokeh/server/static/ /home/myusername/public_html/bokeh-static/
```

and then modify my code as follows:

```
import bokeh.plotting as bplt
import numpy as np

x=np.random.random(100)
y=np.random.random(100)

bplt.output_file("t.html")
plot=bplt.line(x,y)


#the following line refers to the bokeh rsynced to my directory
print plot.create_html_snippet(
           static_path='http://www.my_server_website/~myusername/bokeh-static/', 
           embed_base_url = 'http://www.my_server_website/~myusername/where_.js_file_is_located')
```

and then obviously copy the generated html into the `testembed.html`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

UPDATE: the `create_html_snippet` function mentioned in the original question was deprecated and removed years ago. There are now various newer ways to embed Bokeh content available in the [`bokeh.embed`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html) module. This answer will summarize some of them.

## Standalone Content

Standalone Bokeh content is pure HTML/JS/CSS that is not backed by a running Bokeh server. However, standalone Bokeh content can still be highly interactive, with plot tools (e.g. pan, zoom, selection), linked brushing, and widgets that trigger CustomJS actions. There are several ways to embed standalone content:

### `json_item`

If you would like to create a pure JSON representation of the content that can be loaded by JS functions, you can use the [`json_item`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#json-items) function. As an example, you might server the JSON from a Flask endpoint:

```
@app.route('/plot')
def plot():
    p = make_plot('petal_width', 'petal_length')
    return json.dumps(json_item(p, "myplot"))
```

Then the page can load and render the content with JavaScript code like this:

```
<div id="myplot"></div>

<script>
fetch('/plot')
    .then(function(response) { return response.json(); })
    .then(function(item) { Bokeh.embed.embed_item(item); })
</script>
```

This assumes you have loaded the BokehJS library on the page, e.g. by templating `CDN.render()` in the `<head>` of the page. See a [complete minimal example here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/1.0.4/examples/embed/json_item.py).

### `components`

If you would like to generate a simple `<script>` tag and `<div>` that can be templated into a page to, you can use the [`components`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components) function:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.embed import components

plot = figure()
plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

script, div = components(plot)
```

The returned `script` and `div` (or divs it you pass multiple items) can be inserted in to page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Scatter Plots</title>

        <!-- COPY/PASTE BOKEHJS RESOURCES HERE -->

        <!-- COPY/PASTE SCRIPT HERE -->

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- INSERT DIVS HERE -->
    </body>
</html>
```

As above, you will need to hardcode or template the BokehJS JS and CSS resources in the page head, e.g. with `CDN.render()`

### `file_html`

If you want to generate entire complete HTML pages (i.e. including `<head></head><body></body>`), you can use the [`file_html`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#html-files) function:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import file_html

plot = figure()
plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

html = file_html(plot, CDN, "my plot")
```

This generates a basic page that can be saved or served, etc. If desired you can also supply your own Jinja template (see docs for details).

## Bokeh Server Applications

Bokeh server applications can connect Bokeh plots and widgets to a live running Python process, so that events like UI interactions, making selections, or widget manipulations can trigger real Python code (e.g. Pandas or scikit-learn).

To embed a basic Bokeh application in a page template, the most common method is to use `server_document`:

```
from bokeh.embed import server_document
script = server_document("https://demo.bokeh.org/slider")
```

The returned `script` can be templated anywhere in an HTML page, and the Bokeh application will appear there. There are many other possibilities, e.g. embedding app components individually, customizing sessions for users, or running behind proxies/load balancers. The Bokeh server may also need to be configured to allow access to the embedding page. For full details see the [Running a Bokeh Server](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html) chapter of the Users Guide.

Another, possibly simpler way to "embed" a Bokeh server application, is to use IFrames pointing at the public URL of a running Bokeh app.

Answer (score 3):

*Edit: the information in this answer pertains to **extremely** old versions of Bokeh and is no longer relevant to any usage*

---

`embed_base_url` controls the url path (it can be absolute or relative) that the javascript will search for the embed file in.

`embed_save_loc` controls the directory that python will write out the embed file in.  embed_save_loc isn't necessary when server=True

`static_path` controls the url path (it can absolute or relative) that the javascript will use to construct URLS for bokeh.js and bokeh.css.  It defaults to `http://localhost:5006/static/`, but could just as easily point to a CDN

When running the bokeh server, navigate to `http://localhost:5006/bokeh/generate_embed/static` .  I think this requires you to be running on master because of a bug.

EDIT: a CDN is a "Content Delivery Network" it's just a fancy term for file server. For instance, we host bokeh.js at http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh-0.4.2.js (or http://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh-0.4.2.min.js) for anyone to use.

Comment: See my comment to @bigreddot below, but I also did not understand exactly how the server was relevant; as I understand it I'm not running a server...just trying to embed the javascript statically.  Also what is CDN?